# Create installation USB

Tags: usb, macbook

I am going to buy a laptop that has FreeDos installed. I want to create a bootbale USB drive that will install UBUNTU on it.

Can a create this USB drive using my Macbook Pro? Will it be compatible?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Use unetbootin software

Comment: Thanks for our comment RGG but I'm aftaid I don't know enough about IT to understand your answer. Can you elaborate please? Sorry if I seem dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it will be compatible. I created a Kali Linux bootable USB from an ISO. Just download the ISO on your mac. Unzip it if it is zipped. Then open terminal (use spotlight search if you want). Plug in a USB (be sure to back up the usb if you have anything on it). Make sure the USB is blank by opening disk utility and hitting erase. In terminal type "diskutil list" to list of all the devices plugged into your computer. Unmount the USB by typing "sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/yourdisk(probably something like disk1 or disk2). You may need the "sudo diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/yourdisk" option. After the USB is erased and unmounted, cd(change directory) to whatever directory your ISO is in(most likely donwloads). "cd Downloads". I suggest then renaming the ISO to something short so that it's easy to type. Then burn the ISO to the USB with "sudo dd if=nameofiso(Ubuntu) of=/dev/disk1s1(where disk1 is your disk) bs=1M". Be very careful with the dd command, make the disk is right by unplugging your usb, running "diskutil list", plugging it back in and checking again, because if you get the wrong disk, everything on it will be overwritten. "dd"'s nickname is the data destroyer for a reason. Important: do not remove the usb once you see the output, because the output can be printed before it is finished burning the image. It should take anywhere from 15 minutes to an 1 hour at most. Hope this helps.